# Searching for value in dictionary and return a new dictionary with the corresponding key and value

Tags: python, dictionary, search

So lets say I have this dictionary of preschool kids. The key is the names and the values represent : favorite color, age, and hair color.

```
    preschool_kids={"Suzie":("purple", 4, "brown"), 
"Michael":("blue", 3, "blond"), "Jane":("purple",5, "black")}
```

So I'm testing to see which of these student's favorite color is purple, and wanting the following output:

```
{"Suzie":("purple", 4, "brown"),"Jane":("purple",5, "black")}
```

I've done the following (using dictionary above)trying to get that result:

```
def search(values, color):
    d={}
    for key,value in preschool_kids.items():
        colors=value[0]

        if color in colors:
            d= (key, value)
            print(d)

print (search(preschool_kids, "purple"))
```

but instead I keep coming out with :

```
('Suzie', ('purple', 4, 'brown'))
('Jane', ('purple', 5, 'black'))
```

How can I get it to form a new dictionary with the search results from my code instead of a tuple? It definitely seems to be giving me the right things I'm asking for, but just not in the output I want.

Also, since I'm quite new to Python, I'd rather not import things, since I don't have much experience or full understanding of the different imported libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

`d = (key,value)` is the wrong way to assign a key to a value in a dictionary. This creates a *tuple* `(key,value)` and assigns it to `d`, overwriting its previous existence as a dictionary.

### The Best Solution

Use a dictionary comprehension. This is the smart way:

```
result = {k: v for k,v in preschool_kids.items() if v[0] == color}
```

This creates a new dictionary with only the results you want.

### The Naive Solution (and the right way to assign in dictionaries)

The naive way to do it is:

```
d={}
for key,value in preschool_kids.items():
    if value[0] == color:
        d[key] = value # right way to assign a value to a key
print(d) # this prints the entire dictionary, and not the dictionary at each step
```

Comment: Wow, this was really useful for me. Thanks for showing the "for dummies" (like me) version of it as well as a more simplified and efficient way of getting the same accomplished. Just started working with dictionaries maybe 2 weeks ago, so this is all still pretty new to me and as you can see I got a little confused with creating that new dictionary from my attempt. Great explanation!

Comment: @Nick No problem, that's what we're here for :)

Answer (score 0):

You're close!  You just need to update the dictionary you're building in your function to map the student's name to their attributes and return it:

```
preschool_kids = {
    "Suzie": ("purple", 4, "brown"),
    "Michael": ("blue", 3, "blond"), "Jane":("purple",5, "black")
}

def search(values, color):
    students_with_favorite_color = {}
    for name,attrs in preschool_kids.items():
        students_favorite_color = attrs[0]

        if students_favorite_color == color:
            students_with_favorite_color[name] = attrs

    return students_with_favorite_color

print(search(preschool_kids, 'purple'))
```

Comment: This works, but I find it's always useful not to change the OP's variable name choices (for their benefit - it's not our code to change) :)